# Trying to use Symbols to represent numerous fields

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes, qgis-2.12

I am using QGIS 2.12 in an Archaeological setting. I have populated a layer with features that represent burials and I have the intent for symbols to appear in the burial polygons to represent the type of artifacts(shell beads, types of pendants, etc.) found in them. I have 6 different items I want to represent on these. Some burials have 1 of these items, some burials have all 6.

How do I go about setting it up so that the fields can all be represented? Can I use rule based to do it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @javause! Yes, **rule-based** would be the way to go. How are features represented in the artifact fields if there are or are not any items present? Do they have a `yes` or `no`; `True` or `False` etc?

Comment: I simply created a field for each of the items I want to represent and placed "Yes" in the fields that contain and left the other fields null.

Comment: @Joseph Sorry that reply was so dry I was trying to head to a meeting. Yeah, I can easily add No to the fields if needed, there are not a lot of items I am working with. Thank you for the quick reply and the welcome. Not entirely sure how this site functions, so I assume @ gets your attention!

Comment: No need to apologise buddy! And yes, using @ infront of a name shows up as a red inbox message. I haven't used multiple symbology for various fields for each feature but I _may_ have some idea. Will need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a bit of fun as I haven't did this before but one way of representing multiple items for individual features is to use the **Rule-based** style and create 2 symbol layers for each rule (**Centroid fill** and **SVG marker**). I thought this is easier than filling entire polygons with mixtures of colours. Just to show the final outcome first (if you don't like it, don't bother reading the rest!):

[image: Result]

You may notice that both the legends and the style properties do not show the keys correctly, this is due to the placement of the SVG images used and is mentioned later. The following is the style rules I used for 6 types of artifacts (*note that double quotes are used for field names and single quotes for values*):

[image: Style properties]

Most work is getting the symbology correct in terms of representation and alignment. To do something similar as above, add a new rule by clicking the green plus sign:

[image: Add rule]

Select the **Simple fill** property and change the *Symbol layer type* to **Centroid fill**:

[image: Centroid fill]

Next, select the **Simple marker** property and change the *Symbol layer type* to **SVG marker**:

[image: SVG marker]

Using the "Beads" item as an example, you can set the SVG image (half of my SVGs were downloaded), size and very importantly, the **Offset X,Y**. I placed each SVG on an imaginary 3x2 grid but this is easily changed. Note that changing the offset will affect the legend key which is quite annoying. Do these steps for each item and hopefully you will have a much better looking map than what I did! And it doesn't have to be SVGs, you could also use simple coloured dots or letters, just change the marker type to **Simple marker** or **Font marker** etc.

[image: SVG properties]

Hope this helps!